# Hash string when inserted into Derby Database

Tags: java, derby

In MySQL there are built-in methods that can be used to turn plaintext strings into hashes as they are inserted into a database. (See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) link) Are there equivalent methods or techniques for doing the same in Apache Derby?

I know of, and can use, the MessageDigest class within Java to hash plaintext strings. I found a program that seemingly does it ([here](http://marcellmajor.com/derbyhash.html)) but looking at the date it seems pretty outdated (plus when I look for some of the methods and classes they don't seem to appear in the most recent API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use this code snippet for SHA1:

```
String hash = null;
    try
    {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        digest.update(toHash.getBytes(), 0, toHash.length());
        hash = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use simple `String digest = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(plainText)` from Apache Commons Codecs library?

Comment: It doesn't seem like I can access the DigestUtils class. Are there any imports I need to have?

Comment: Yes, you can find this library (and many others) at Apache Commons website: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/